# Construction of a splitting field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, splitting-field

Building splitting field over $\mathbb Q$  of $f(x) = x^{5} - 3$.

I know that the criterion of Eisenstein that $f(x)$ is irreducible with $p=3$.

Then $f(x)$ has five distinct roots. I know that $\alpha = \sqrt[5] 3$ is a root of $f(x)$.

But I'm having problem in finding other roots.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial on mathjax, I suggest you take a look at it.

Comment: Ok, I will look.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Take a $5$-th root of unit $\xi \neq 1$. Then let $\alpha = \sqrt[5]{3}$ and you have that $\alpha, \alpha\xi, \alpha\xi^2, \alpha\xi^3, \alpha\xi^4$ are the roots of $f(x) = x^5 - 3$.